# Action Script 3. How to prevent lag bugs issues in flash games?

Tags: sql, performance, actionscript-3, flash, lag

How to prevent lag bugs issues in flash games? For example If game have countdown timer 1 minute and player have to catch that much items that possible.

Here are following lag bugs issues:

- If items moving (don't have static position) - that higher lag player
  have, that slower items move;
- Timer starting count slowly when player have lags (CPU usage 90-100%).

So for example If player without lags can get 100 points, player with *slow / bad* computer can get 4-6x more, like 400-600.

---

I think that because It's on client side, but how to move It to server side? Should I insert (and update) countdown time to database? But how to update It on every millisecond?

And how about items position solution? If player have big lags, items moving very very slowly, so easy to click on that, have you any ideas?

Comment: An application lags because it is not optimized or badly written. You prevent lag by learning how to be a better coder or by learning how to optimize your app. Flash games do not lag, coders makes their game lag or they don't.

Comment: Sorry, but you really wrong or I misunderstand you. Flash games really can lag depending on player's computer. I can reach 100% CPU usage and everything will became slowly in game that because I have lags. So in this case I can easy to catch moving items, etc. So that's why I'm asking for suggestions how to solve It.

Comment: Lag is the time between user input and the reaction of a game. Lag is usually mentioned when talking about network connection. For example, user presses button, game client sends data to server, server processes data and sends back the result, game client draws the result. Time measured between pressing button and getting result is the lag. What you are talking about probably isn't lag but simply an application putting too much load on the processor. You need to optimize your application.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the functionality to the server side doesn't solve the problem.
Now if there are many players connected to the server, the server will lag and give those players more time to react.

To make your logic independent from lag, do not base it on the screen update.
Because this assumes a constant time between screen updates (or frames)

Instead, make your logic based on the actual time that passed between frames.
Use getTimer to measure how much time passed between the current and the last frame.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html

Of course, your logic should include calculations for what happens in between frames.

Answer (score 0):

In order to *mostly* fix speed issues on the client you need to make all your speed related code based on actual time, not frames. For example:

Here is a fairly typical example code used to move an object based on frames:

```
// speed = pixels per frame
var xSpeed:Number = 5;
var ySpeed:Number = 5;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function update(e:Event):void {
    player.x += xSpeed;
    player.y += ySpeed;
}
```

While this code is simple and good enough for a single client, it is very dependent on the frame rate, and as you know the frame rate is very "elastic" and actual frame rate is heavily influenced by the client CPU speed.

Instead, here is an example where the movement is based on actual elapsed time:

```
// speed = pixels per second
var xSpeed:Number = 5 * stage.frameRate;
var ySpeed:Number = 5 * stage.frameRate;

var lastTime:int = getTimer();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function update(e:Event):void {
    var currentTime:int = getTimer();
    var elapsedSeconds:Number = (currentTime - lastTime) / 1000;
    player.x += xSpeed * elapsedSeconds;
    player.y += ySpeed * elapsedSeconds;

    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

The crucial part here is that the current time is tracked using `getTimer()`, and each update moves the `player` based on the actual elapsed time, not a fixed amount. I set the `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` to `5 * stage.frameRate` to illustrate how it can be equivelent to the other example, but you don't have to do it that way. The end result is that the second example would have consistent speed of movement regardless of the actual frame rate.